# Error CrushLoopBackOff to start k8s Dashboard

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I try to install dashboard to clear private k8s cluster (without internet connection).
I did according to this instruction https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard.
When start apply recomended.yaml:
metrics scrapper start successfully, but dashboard show error CrashLoopBackOff permanently.

Docker Version: 19.03.6
K8s version: 1.23.4

Containers status:

```
user@k8s-master1:~/images$ sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE   IP             NODE              NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system            coredns-64897985d-9kgwl                      1/1     Running            0             39h   10.224.0.3     k8s-master1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-64897985d-kmcvf                      1/1     Running            0             39h   10.224.0.2     k8s-master1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            etcd-k8s-master1                             1/1     Running            3             39h   10.12.21.157   k8s-master1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-k8s-master1                   1/1     Running            3             39h   10.12.21.157   k8s-master1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-k8s-master1          1/1     Running            2             39h   10.12.21.157   k8s-master1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-5cqrc                        1/1     Running            1 (15h ago)   39h   10.12.21.165   k8s-worker1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-8xfjt                        1/1     Running            0             39h   10.12.21.157   k8s-master1   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-77m6t                             1/1     Running            1 (15h ago)   39h   10.12.21.165   k8s-worker1.era   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-zslrc                             1/1     Running            0             39h   10.12.21.157   k8s-master1.era   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-k8s-master1                   1/1     Running            3             39h   10.12.21.157   k8s-master1.era   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-799d786dbf-ww8d2   1/1     Running            0             21m   10.224.1.33    k8s-worker1.era   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5n4bl        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (56s ago)   21m   10.224.1.34    k8s-worker1.era   <none>           <none>
```

Containers log:

```
user@k8s-master1:~/images$ sudo kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5n4bl --namespace="kubernetes-dashboard" --tail=-1 --follow=true
2022/03/23 05:37:23 Starting overwatch
2022/03/23 05:37:23 Using namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
2022/03/23 05:37:23 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2022/03/23 05:37:23 Using secret token for csrf signing
2022/03/23 05:37:23 Initializing csrf token from kubernetes-dashboard-csrf secret
panic: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/secrets/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.(*csrfTokenManager).init(0xc00055faf0)
        /home/runner/work/dashboard/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:41 +0x30e
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.NewCsrfTokenManager(...)
        /home/runner/work/dashboard/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:66
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).initCSRFKey(0xc000468180)
        /home/runner/work/dashboard/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:527 +0x94
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).init(0x194fa64)
        /home/runner/work/dashboard/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:495 +0x32
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.NewClientManager(...)
        /home/runner/work/dashboard/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:594
main.main()
        /home/runner/work/dashboard/dashboard/src/app/backend/dashboard.go:95 +0x1cf


user@k8s-master1:~/images$ sudo kubectl logs dashboard-metrics-scraper-799d786dbf-ww8d2 --namespace="kubernetes-dashboard" --tail=-1 --follow=true
{"level":"info","msg":"Kubernetes host: https://10.96.0.1:443","time":"2022-03-23T05:17:21Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Namespace(s): []","time":"2022-03-23T05:17:21Z"}
10.224.1.1 - - [23/Mar/2022:05:18:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "" "kube-probe/1.23"
10.224.1.1 - - [23/Mar/2022:05:18:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "" "kube-probe/1.23"
10.224.1.1 - - [23/Mar/2022:05:18:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "" "kube-probe/1.23"
10.224.1.1 - - [23/Mar/2022:05:18:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "" "kube-probe/1.23"
10.224.1.1 - - [23/Mar/2022:05:18:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "" "kube-probe/1.23"
10.224.1.1 - - [23/Mar/2022:05:18:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "" "kube-probe/1.23"
```

Worker-node logs from /var/log/syslog:

```
Mar 22 17:39:06 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959946.6236] connectivity: (ens3) timed out
Mar 22 17:39:15 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:39:15.874414    1514 topology_manager.go:200] "Topology Admit Handler"
Mar 22 17:39:15 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: Created slice libcontainer container kubepods-besteffort-pod7fc08bc9_9992_4f8d_9a03_6ab174479715.slice.
Mar 22 17:39:15 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:39:15.890731    1514 topology_manager.go:200] "Topology Admit Handler"
Mar 22 17:39:15 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: Created slice libcontainer container kubepods-besteffort-poda226e365_e55c_438a_b31f_9fb54ec2c0cd.slice.
Mar 22 17:39:15 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:39:15.969404    1514 reconciler.go:221] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume \"tmp-volume\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/empty-dir/7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715-tmp-volume\") pod \"kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59\" (UID: \"7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715\") " pod="kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59"
Mar 22 17:39:15 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:39:15.969446    1514 reconciler.go:221] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume \"kube-api-access-tlh9b\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/projected/7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715-kube-api-access-tlh9b\") pod \"kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59\" (UID: \"7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715\") " pod="kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59"
Mar 22 17:39:15 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:39:15.969468    1514 reconciler.go:221] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume \"tmp-volume\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/empty-dir/a226e365-e55c-438a-b31f-9fb54ec2c0cd-tmp-volume\") pod \"dashboard-metrics-scraper-799d786dbf-6x7b5\" (UID: \"a226e365-e55c-438a-b31f-9fb54ec2c0cd\") " pod="kubernetes-dashboard/dashboard-metrics-scraper-799d786dbf-6x7b5"
Mar 22 17:39:15 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:39:15.969489    1514 reconciler.go:221] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume \"kubernetes-dashboard-certs\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/secret/7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715-kubernetes-dashboard-certs\") pod \"kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59\" (UID: \"7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715\") " pod="kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59"
Mar 22 17:39:15 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:39:15.969508    1514 reconciler.go:221] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume \"kube-api-access-9g2vd\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/projected/a226e365-e55c-438a-b31f-9fb54ec2c0cd-kube-api-access-9g2vd\") pod \"dashboard-metrics-scraper-799d786dbf-6x7b5\" (UID: \"a226e365-e55c-438a-b31f-9fb54ec2c0cd\") " pod="kubernetes-dashboard/dashboard-metrics-scraper-799d786dbf-6x7b5"
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 containerd[1357]: time="2022-03-22T17:39:16.322790061+03:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address=/containerd-shim/883437e7a51b5599bab43f814d5c337b9fe3c2751e24c906c656ee8eac8256bd.sock debug=false pid=9001
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 containerd[1357]: time="2022-03-22T17:39:16.324394320+03:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address=/containerd-shim/24b06da95eb0fcb204fcddd18385706898f16ea49f66eb072883057290b6250f.sock debug=false pid=9006
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container f9e95ee9b501cd765b93c370bfa58dd38c0281f627c604fc537d5bfae075e4f5.
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container e5c0d5721a2f52e0d6fae6818447eda8578b45b51ef6e0a497d460c1eff6579c.
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.907330] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth4ea29f8d: link becomes ready
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959956.5808] device (veth4ea29f8d): carrier: link connected
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 systemd-udevd[9166]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 systemd-udevd[9166]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth4ea29f8d: No such file or directory
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959956.5817] manager: (veth4ea29f8d): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 systemd-udevd[9167]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 systemd-udevd[9167]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth7259e59e: No such file or directory
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959956.5823] device (veth7259e59e): carrier: link connected
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959956.5827] manager: (veth7259e59e): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959956.5830] device (cni0): carrier: link connected
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955524] cni0: port 1(veth4ea29f8d) entered blocking state
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955526] cni0: port 1(veth4ea29f8d) entered disabled state
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955579] device veth4ea29f8d entered promiscuous mode
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955610] cni0: port 1(veth4ea29f8d) entered blocking state
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955612] cni0: port 1(veth4ea29f8d) entered forwarding state
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955816] cni0: port 2(veth7259e59e) entered blocking state
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955818] cni0: port 2(veth7259e59e) entered disabled state
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955871] device veth7259e59e entered promiscuous mode
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955888] cni0: port 2(veth7259e59e) entered blocking state
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kernel: [  667.955889] cni0: port 2(veth7259e59e) entered forwarding state
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959956.5902] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth7259e59e, iface: veth7259e59e)
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959956.5902] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth7259e59e, iface: veth7259e59e): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959956.5908] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth4ea29f8d, iface: veth4ea29f8d)
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 NetworkManager[945]: <info>  [1647959956.5908] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth4ea29f8d, iface: veth4ea29f8d): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: map[string]interface {}{"cniVersion":"0.3.1", "hairpinMode":true, "ipMasq":false, "ipam":map[string]interface {}{"ranges":[][]map[string]interface {}{[]map[string]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"subnet":"10.224.1.0/24"}}}, "routes":[]types.Route{types.Route{Dst:net.IPNet{IP:net.IP{0xa, 0xf4, 0x0, 0x0}, Mask:net.IPMask{0xff, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0}}, GW:net.IP(nil)}}, "type":"host-local"}, "isDefaultGateway":true, "isGateway":true, "mtu":(*uint)(0xc0000b28e8), "name":"cbr0", "type":"bridge"}
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: {"cniVersion":"0.3.1","hairpinMode":true,"ipMasq":false,"ipam":{"ranges":[[{"subnet":"10.224.1.0/24"}]],"routes":[{"dst":"10.244.0.0/16"}],"type":"host-local"},"isDefaultGateway":true,"isGateway":true,"mtu":1450,"name":"cbr0","type":"bridge"}
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: map[string]interface {}{"cniVersion":"0.3.1", "hairpinMode":true, "ipMasq":false, "ipam":map[string]interface {}{"ranges":[][]map[string]interface {}{[]map[string]interface {}{map[string]interface {}{"subnet":"10.224.1.0/24"}}}, "routes":[]types.Route{types.Route{Dst:net.IPNet{IP:net.IP{0xa, 0xf4, 0x0, 0x0}, Mask:net.IPMask{0xff, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0}}, GW:net.IP(nil)}}, "type":"host-local"}, "isDefaultGateway":true, "isGateway":true, "mtu":(*uint)(0xc000014938), "name":"cbr0", "type":"bridge"}
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 containerd[1357]: time="2022-03-22T17:39:16.752605404+03:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address=/containerd-shim/5e2d01620875c9a1e0f82bd5083e71aec9510daa518af452ae29d50635a5f841.sock debug=false pid=9230
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 containerd[1357]: time="2022-03-22T17:39:16.755987710+03:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address=/containerd-shim/b57a694fc62e0e5ddc906714e76e18b06913d4d8726671d3eb1e5ad10c860140.sock debug=false pid=9244
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container 5eda35ba11cfc0d43b1fb1065b6f28890f2741ea4999ece6c5ad9c707c1b2aae.
Mar 22 17:39:16 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container df2a62380c546b35185ac422f3c660642f2275405c5099b3ba0ff9a117fdda61.
Mar 22 17:39:17 k8s-worker1 avahi-daemon[790]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface veth4ea29f8d.IPv6 with address fe80::5488:49ff:fe0d:d8dc.
Mar 22 17:39:17 k8s-worker1 avahi-daemon[790]: New relevant interface veth4ea29f8d.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar 22 17:39:17 k8s-worker1 avahi-daemon[790]: Registering new address record for fe80::5488:49ff:fe0d:d8dc on veth4ea29f8d.*.
Mar 22 17:39:17 k8s-worker1 avahi-daemon[790]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface veth7259e59e.IPv6 with address fe80::60e1:5eff:fe1d:10c6.
Mar 22 17:39:17 k8s-worker1 avahi-daemon[790]: New relevant interface veth7259e59e.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar 22 17:39:17 k8s-worker1 avahi-daemon[790]: Registering new address record for fe80::60e1:5eff:fe1d:10c6 on veth7259e59e.*.
Mar 22 17:39:32 k8s-worker1 systemd-resolved[501]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 10.12.21.2.
Mar 22 17:39:37 k8s-worker1 systemd-resolved[501]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 10.12.21.120.
Mar 22 17:39:46 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: docker-5eda35ba11cfc0d43b1fb1065b6f28890f2741ea4999ece6c5ad9c707c1b2aae.scope: Consumed 51ms CPU time
Mar 22 17:39:46 k8s-worker1 containerd[1357]: time="2022-03-22T17:39:46.878548665+03:00" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=5eda35ba11cfc0d43b1fb1065b6f28890f2741ea4999ece6c5ad9c707c1b2aae
Mar 22 17:39:46 k8s-worker1 dockerd[1517]: time="2022-03-22T17:39:46.888692147+03:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Mar 22 17:39:47 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: {"cniVersion":"0.3.1","hairpinMode":true,"ipMasq":false,"ipam":{"ranges":[[{"subnet":"10.224.1.0/24"}]],"routes":[{"dst":"10.244.0.0/16"}],"type":"host-local"},"isDefaultGateway":true,"isGateway":true,"mtu":1450,"name":"cbr0","type":"bridge"}I0322 17:39:47.347140    1514 scope.go:110] "RemoveContainer" containerID="5eda35ba11cfc0d43b1fb1065b6f28890f2741ea4999ece6c5ad9c707c1b2aae"
Mar 22 17:39:47 k8s-worker1 containerd[1357]: time="2022-03-22T17:39:47.410154268+03:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address=/containerd-shim/aeed00521eedeab1bcd9c24b35bf6f3e4f7ace60e73a768a716086e00c0c4bef.sock debug=false pid=9620
Mar 22 17:39:47 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container 8b83bcb2998b0248e79652975f0862cf5f648d60f0506ed8242b2450e27cdac3.
Mar 22 17:39:58 k8s-worker1 whoopsie[1543]: [17:39:58] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 22 17:40:17 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: docker-8b83bcb2998b0248e79652975f0862cf5f648d60f0506ed8242b2450e27cdac3.scope: Consumed 46ms CPU time
Mar 22 17:40:17 k8s-worker1 containerd[1357]: time="2022-03-22T17:40:17.527541322+03:00" level=info msg="shim reaped" id=8b83bcb2998b0248e79652975f0862cf5f648d60f0506ed8242b2450e27cdac3
Mar 22 17:40:17 k8s-worker1 dockerd[1517]: time="2022-03-22T17:40:17.537731616+03:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Mar 22 17:40:18 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:40:18.458400    1514 scope.go:110] "RemoveContainer" containerID="5eda35ba11cfc0d43b1fb1065b6f28890f2741ea4999ece6c5ad9c707c1b2aae"
Mar 22 17:40:18 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:40:18.458815    1514 scope.go:110] "RemoveContainer" containerID="8b83bcb2998b0248e79652975f0862cf5f648d60f0506ed8242b2450e27cdac3"
Mar 22 17:40:18 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: E0322 17:40:18.459109    1514 pod_workers.go:919] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kubernetes-dashboard\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 10s restarting failed container=kubernetes-dashboard pod=kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59_kubernetes-dashboard(7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715)\"" pod="kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59" podUID=7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715
Mar 22 17:40:25 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:40:25.875469    1514 scope.go:110] "RemoveContainer" containerID="8b83bcb2998b0248e79652975f0862cf5f648d60f0506ed8242b2450e27cdac3"
Mar 22 17:40:25 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: E0322 17:40:25.875672    1514 pod_workers.go:919] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kubernetes-dashboard\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 10s restarting failed container=kubernetes-dashboard pod=kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59_kubernetes-dashboard(7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715)\"" pod="kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard-7b65cf66c4-5cp59" podUID=7fc08bc9-9992-4f8d-9a03-6ab174479715
Mar 22 17:40:38 k8s-worker1 kubelet[1514]: I0322 17:40:38.103479    1514 scope.go:110] "RemoveContainer" containerID="8b83bcb2998b0248e79652975f0862cf5f648d60f0506ed8242b2450e27cdac3"
Mar 22 17:40:38 k8s-worker1 containerd[1357]: time="2022-03-22T17:40:38.174450523+03:00" level=info msg="shim containerd-shim started" address=/containerd-shim/05e57eded5ea65217590df57468a79098fe8ca0dc53767f60a953cd740a21eeb.sock debug=false pid=10037
Mar 22 17:40:38 k8s-worker1 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container bed40cfd651d6d9f82699aeb3b8d37712e150d0720e0f40ce03453e2ab5e8808.
```

Comment: The logs for the crash looping pod will be much more useful than the kublet logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the dashboard container is installed on the worker node. In the recommended.yaml file I included installation on the control machine: `nodeName: k8s-master1`. it works.

Final yaml file:

```yaml
# apiVersion: v1
# kind: Namespace
# metadata:
#   name: kubernetes-dashboard

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
      nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard

---

# apiVersion: v1
# kind: Secret
# metadata:
#   labels:
#     k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
#   name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
#   namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
# type: Opaque

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-csrf
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
type: Opaque
data:
  csrf: ""

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
type: Opaque

---

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-settings
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard

---

kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
rules:
  # Allow Dashboard to get, update and delete Dashboard exclusive secrets.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder", "kubernetes-dashboard-certs", "kubernetes-dashboard-csrf"]
    verbs: ["get", "update", "delete"]
    # Allow Dashboard to get and update 'kubernetes-dashboard-settings' config map.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-settings"]
    verbs: ["get", "update"]
    # Allow Dashboard to get metrics.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services"]
    resourceNames: ["heapster", "dashboard-metrics-scraper"]
    verbs: ["proxy"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services/proxy"]
    resourceNames: ["heapster", "http:heapster:", "https:heapster:", "dashboard-metrics-scraper", "http:dashboard-metrics-scraper"]
    verbs: ["get"]

---

kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
rules:
  # Allow Metrics Scraper to get metrics from the Metrics server
  - apiGroups: ["metrics.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["pods", "nodes"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    namespace: kubernetes-dashboard

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    namespace: kubernetes-dashboard

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    spec:
      nodeName: k8s-master1
      securityContext:
        seccompProfile:
          type: RuntimeDefault
      containers:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard
          image: kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.5.1
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          args:
            - --auto-generate-certificates
            - --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
            # Uncomment the following line to manually specify Kubernetes API server Host
            # If not specified, Dashboard will attempt to auto discover the API server and connect
            # to it. Uncomment only if the default does not work.
            # - --apiserver-host=http://my-address:port
          volumeMounts:
            - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
              mountPath: /certs
              # Create on-disk volume to store exec logs
            - mountPath: /tmp
              name: tmp-volume
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: HTTPS
              path: /
              port: 8443
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            runAsUser: 1001
            runAsGroup: 2001
      volumes:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
          secret:
            secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
        - name: tmp-volume
          emptyDir: {}
      serviceAccountName: kubernetes-dashboard
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      # Comment the following tolerations if Dashboard must not be deployed on master
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: dashboard-metrics-scraper
  name: dashboard-metrics-scraper
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    k8s-app: dashboard-metrics-scraper

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: dashboard-metrics-scraper
  name: dashboard-metrics-scraper
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: dashboard-metrics-scraper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: dashboard-metrics-scraper
    spec:
      nodeName: k8s-master1
      securityContext:
        seccompProfile:
          type: RuntimeDefault
      containers:
        - name: dashboard-metrics-scraper
          image: kubernetesui/metrics-scraper:v1.0.7
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: HTTP
              path: /
              port: 8000
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /tmp
            name: tmp-volume
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            runAsUser: 1001
            runAsGroup: 2001
      serviceAccountName: kubernetes-dashboard
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      # Comment the following tolerations if Dashboard must not be deployed on master
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      volumes:
        - name: tmp-volume
          emptyDir: {}
```